# SOSL - Return correct related record type

Tags: sosl

I'm having an issue with the `type` field on related records from an SOSL search.

In our organization, Leads can be owned by either a User or a Group/Queue and Accounts can only be owned by Users.

**SOSL Query**

```
FIND 
    {test@test.com} IN Email Fields 
RETURNING 
    Lead(Id, OwnerId, Status, Owner.Email, Owner.Name), 
    Account(Id, OwnerId, Type, Owner.Email, Owner.Name)
```

My result set contains all the required fields, but the owner type on Leads does not show the correct type; it always shows `Name` as the type. Accounts show correctly.

To get the correct Owner Type, I'm currently comparing the `OwnerId` with the `keyPrefix` from the `sObject` description to determine whether the Lead is owned by a User or a Group.

**Is there a way to make the SOSL Search return the correct owner type for Leads?**

I'm using the Force.com PHP Toolkit and the SOAP API to retrieve the data. An example result set is below.

**Result Set**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SObject Object
        (
            [type] => Lead
            [fields] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [OwnerId] => 00570000000xxxAA2
                    [Status] => Unverified
                    [Owner] => SObject Object
                        (
                            [type] => Name             (This should be User)
                            [fields] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Email] => user1@myorg.com
                                    [Name] => Joe User
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Id] => 00Q7000000xnxnxEAO
        )

    [1] => SObject Object
        (
            [type] => Lead
            [fields] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [OwnerId] => 00G00000000xgxgxAA2
                    [Status] => Unverified
                    [Owner] => SObject Object
                        (
                            [type] => Name             (This should be Group)
                            [fields] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Email] => group@myorg.com
                                    [Name] => US/CN
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Id] => 00Q7000000xlxlxEAO
        )

    [2] => SObject Object
        (
            [type] => Account
            [fields] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [OwnerId] => 0057000000xaxaxAAI
                    [Type] => Prospect
                    [Owner] => SObject Object
                        (
                            [type] => User             (This is correct)
                            [fields] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Email] => user2@myorg.com
                                    [Name] => Jane User
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Id] => 0017000000xnxnxAAK
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried Owner.Type instead of just Type?

Comment: `Owner.Type` is not a valid field. Type isn't really a Property of the record; it's a description of the record.

Comment: Well I just ran this in execute anon and it works

list<Lead> leads = [Select Id, Name, OwnerId, Owner.Type From Lead Limit 25];
For(Lead l: leads){
 if(l.Owner.Type == 'User'){
  system.debug('Its a user');
 }
 if(l.Owner.Type == 'Queue'){
  system.debug('Its a queue');
 }
}

Comment: If I add `Owner.Type` into the query, I get and API exception because `Owner.Type` is an invalid field for the User object type.

Comment: You are using SOQL not SOSL ... I need to do an SOSL search (`FIND`) ...

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes.  There's the issue.  My apologies.  I was thinking in SOQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory, that polymorphic field doesn't quite work as expected in this case. I vaguely recall that "Name" is always returned, and that there may not be a SOSL-native way to get the return type. Like I said, vague recollection, but it's supported by the fact that the SOSL docs don't discuss polymorphic fields while the SOQL docs do refer to them.

Couple workarounds I can think of:

- inspecting the key prefix isn't that bad a workaround, IMO. I use key prefix inspection pretty regularly in other contexts. It's cheap, and it works.
- you could create a custom formula (text) field on lead, called something like "Owner Type", with a formula that refers to the polymorphic owner field (relatively new feature) and have your SOSL return it - the formula would be something like `IF(ISBLANK(Owner:Queue.Id), "User", "Queue")` - I have tested this and it does work.

Like I said, there may be a SOSL-native way I'm not aware, but either of those other approaches above should work fine also.

Comment: Yep ... I'm just going to keep checking the prefix ... Thanks for your input!